# UnitOfWork with Multiple Datasource in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently working on a .NET application where I need to connect to multiple datasources. I am using NHibernate as my ORM, implementing the Unit of Work pattern, Clean Architecture principles, and Mediator pattern. However, I am facing challenges in configuring my application to connect to different databases based on specific criteria.

In my application, I have implemented the Unit of Work pattern with NHibernate. Here's a snippet of my code where I configure NHibernate sessions dynamically based on the provided session factory name:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddHibernate(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString, string sessionFactoryName)
    {
        IPersistenceConfigurer cfg = OracleDataClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ConnectionString(connectionString).Provider<DriverConnectionProvider>().Driver<Driver.OracleManagedDataClientDriver>();
        var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure().Database(cfg)
            .ExposeConfiguration(c => {
                c.EventListeners.DeleteEventListeners = new IDeleteEventListener[] { new NHEventListener() };
                c.AppendListeners(ListenerType.PreInsert, new IPreInsertEventListener[] { new NHEventListener() });
                c.AppendListeners(ListenerType.PreUpdate, new IPreUpdateEventListener[] { new NHEventListener() });
            })
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<NhUnitOfWork>())
            .BuildSessionFactory();

        services.AddSingleton(sessionFactory);
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork>(provider => new NhUnitOfWork(provider.GetService<ISessionFactory>(), sessionFactoryName));

        return services;
    }
```

Despite these efforts, I am encountering issues during runtime. It appears that the correct session factory and connection string are not being used when I create the NHibernate session. Specifically, when I debug the application, the session factory name parameter that I pass in my AddHibernate function retains the value of the last database I configure, rather than using the name provided in the Program.cs file.

Program.cs

```
services.AddHibernate(“connection1”, “SessionFactory1");
services.AddHibernate(“connection2”, “SessionFactory2");
services.AddHibernate(“connection3”, “SessionFactory3");
```

I am seeking advice on how to properly configure my NHibernate sessions and connection strings dynamically based on the specific datasource I want to interact with. If anyone has experience with similar setups or suggestions on how to resolve this issue, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

This is my generic repository NHBaseRepository.cs

```
public abstract class NHBaseRepository<TType> where TType : Entity
{
    protected readonly ISession _dbSession;
 
    protected NHBaseRepository(ISession session)
    {
        _dbSession = session;
    }
 
    public virtual async Task<TType?> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
    {
        return await _dbSession.Query<TType>()
            .Where(obj => obj.DeletedAt == null)
            .Where(obj => obj.Id == id)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
 
    public async Task AddAsync(TType obj)
    {
        await _dbSession.SaveAsync(obj);
    }
 
    public async Task UpdateAsync(TType obj)
    {
        await _dbSession.UpdateAsync(obj);
    }
 
    public void Add(TType obj)
    {
        _dbSession.Save(obj);
    }
 
    public void Update(TType obj)
    {
        _dbSession.Update(obj);
    }
 
    public void Remove(TType obj)
    {
        _dbSession.Delete(obj);
    }
}
```

This is my generic unit of work

```
public class NHUnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork where TContext : IBaseContext
{
    private TContext _context;
 
    public NHUnitOfWork(TContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
 
    public async Task CommitAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await _context.GetCurrentTransaction().CommitAsync();
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            await _session.GetCurrentTransaction().RollbackAsync();
            throw;
        }
    }
 
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _session.Close();
    }
 
    private IUserRepository? _userRepository;
    public IUserRepository User { get { return _userRepository ??= new NHUserRepository(_session); } }
```